# USB keyboard stopped working on my machine

Tags: windows-10, usb, laptop, drivers, keyboard

I have a GSKILL KM780 MX gaming keyboard that's started giving me problems, but only on my particular Windows machine. I'm on the latest (Home) version of Windows and I have the provided manufacturer drivers installed.

One day, I was using it and also programming it's macros using the provided configuration tool, and then I realized that the status keys stopped turning on (caps lock, num lock, scroll lock) when I had pressed them, but their respective functions still worked fine, as in, if I was to press caps lock, it would toggle, etc. I then tried the ol' unplug it and plug it back in. When I reconnected it, the backlight didn't turn on...in fact, nothing works except for the basic HID keyboard. So I can still type on it like a normal keyboard and use the volume wheel, but all the other functionality like the macro keys, media buttons and status indicators won't do anything.

My next idea was to unplug the keyboard again, uninstall the manufacturer driver and restart. I've done that three times now but...no difference. I did also try using the keyboard with no manufacturer software installed. Eventually, I noticed that if I leave the keyboard plugged in while my computer is booting or coming back from hibernate, the backlight will start working, but still no macro keys or status indicators. If I attempt to reconnect it from this state, it goes back to the aforementioned "dark" state.

And finally, I decided to try my keyboard on two other computers. One running Ubuntu and one running Windows 10 Pro. In both cases, the keyboard immediately came back to life with no catches. I can even unplug and plug it back in, and it will continue to work like normal. Thinking maybe this had somehow fixed the issue, I once again tried to plug it back into my computer. Still nothing.

The one and only peculiarity I can find is duplicate entries in Device Manager (**tree sorted by container**):
[image: Screen clip of keyboard listed in Device Manager]

I tried to uninstall the listed drivers, but they all reappear the moment I plug the keyboard in again.

I'm not sure what else to try now. I guess my keyboard *really* dislikes my computer all the sudden.

Comment: Go through each of those items above, right click on it, and select Update Driver. Do that for each and restart the computer.

Comment: @John On each of those items I do that on, it just tells me I already got the best driver.